# Java call function from extended class

Tags: java, extends

I have a variable `Class<? extends JavaPlugin> varname;`.
So, `varname` has to be a class which extends `JavaPlugin`.
I know for sure that `JavaPlugin` has a function `getLogger()`.
But, when I try to call that function using `varname.getLogger()`, it says:

> The method getLogger() is undefined for the type Class

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

`getLogger()` is a method of `JavaPlugin`, but `varname`'s type is `Class<? extends JavaPlugin>`, not `JavaPlugin`. The `Class` class doesn't have that method.

This should pass compilation :

```
JavaPlugin varname = new JavaPlugin ();
varname.getLogger();
```

Comment: And how can I call getLogger() now?

Comment: @BjörnSchönrock What do you mean by "now"? I showed you how.

Comment: woops didn't see that

Comment: But can't I call getLogger from the already existing varname?

Comment: I want to call getLogger and other methods from the `varname` I get with a constructor of my class

Comment: Because maybe that other varname has done a setLogger() or something

Comment: @BjörnSchönrock As long as `varname` is a `Class<? extends JavaPlugin>`, you can't call `getLogger` for it. You can use it to create a new instance of `JavaPlugin` class, and call `getLogger` for that instance.

Comment: How can I call the parent class in a class which extends another class?

Comment: If I have class A, and class B extends A, in B i can call B with this, how can I call A then?

Comment: @BjörnSchönrock what do you mean by "call A"? And how is that related to your original question.

Comment: When I have class B extends A, I can for example pass B in a method parameter using `this`, how can I only pass the parent class (A) then?

Comment: maybe I can pass the JavaPlugin class instead of the class that extends JavaPlugin